# How to remove "disabled" attribute using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, disabled-input

I have to disable inputs at first and then on click of a link to enable them.

This is what I have tried so far, but it doesn't work.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="inputDisabled" value="">
```

jQuery:

```
$("#edit").click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $('.inputDisabled').removeAttr("disabled")
});
```

This shows me `true` and then `false` but nothing changes for the inputs:

```
$("#edit").click(function(event){
   alert('');
   event.preventDefault();
   alert($('.inputDisabled').attr('disabled'));
   $('.inputDisabled').removeAttr("disabled");
   alert($('.inputDisabled').attr('disabled'));
});
```

Comment: I don't see your problem. What are you asking?

Comment: So what is the question? i mean what problem you are facing

Comment: Use prop() - .prop('disabled', false)

Comment: If your problem solved, please tick the accepted (Real) answer for other to know...

Comment: the problem is that it is not disabled after the clic

Comment: i tried all propositions , problem still remaining

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i disable a submit button when checkbox is uncheck?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458531/how-do-i-disable-a-submit-button-when-checkbox-is-uncheck) because that question asks how to toggle, thus both enable and disable

Answer (score 1004, accepted):

**Always** use the **[`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** method to enable or disable elements when using jQuery (see below for why).

In your case, it would be:

```
$("#edit").click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $('.inputDisabled').prop("disabled", false); // Element(s) are now enabled.
});
```

[jsFiddle example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/xPEK4/)

---

> Why use `prop()` when you could use `attr()`/`removeAttr()` to do this?

Basically, `prop()` should be used when getting or setting *properties* (such as `autoplay`, `checked`, `disabled` and `required` amongst others).

While what you want to do *can* technically be done using `attr()`/`removeAttr()`, it doesn't mean it *should* be done - and can cause strange/problematic behaviour, as in this case.

> "The difference between attributes and properties can be important in
> specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the `.attr()` method sometimes
> took property values into account when retrieving some attributes,
> which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the `.prop()`
> method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while
> `.attr()` retrieves attributes."
>
> "Properties generally affect the dynamic state of a DOM element without
> changing the serialized HTML attribute. Examples include the `value`
> property of input elements, the `disabled` property of inputs and
> buttons, or the `checked` property of a checkbox. The `.prop()` method
> should be used to set `disabled` and `checked` instead of the `.attr()`
> method. The `.val()` method should be used for getting and setting
> `value`." - [jQuery documentation for prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

### **Pre-jQuery 3.0 (before 2016)**

The reason why you should use `prop` over `removeAttr()` is that `removeAttr()` completely removes the `disabled` attribute itself - as this method would simply set the corresponding property name to `false`:

> Prior to jQuery 3.0, using .removeAttr() on a boolean attribute such
> as checked, selected, or readonly would also set the corresponding
> named property to false. This behavior was required for ancient
> versions of Internet Explorer but is not correct for modern browsers
> because the attribute represents the initial value and the property
> represents the current (dynamic) value. - [jQuery 3.0 Breaking Changes](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#feature-new-signature-for-jquery-get-and-jquery-post)

While `prop()` merely sets the property's underlying boolean value to false.

Comment: People should also know abut the dirty checkedness flag, which completely breaks `attr` vs `prop` for checkboxes: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-input-checked-dirty except for internal jQuery workaround magic.

Comment: Just a little addition, if you want to disable the checkbox as well as want to uncheck it. We need to uncheck at first and then disable like this jQuery('#no_tax_payer').prop("checked", false).prop("disabled", true); Hope this helps someone !

Comment: Hmm, .prop("disabled", false) doesn't seem to work for me in a button - leaves the 'disabled' attribute in the tag with no value.

Comment: @UpTheCreek was not working for me too. But I discovered to be a scope problem with the 'this' clause (as usual). In the specific case `.prop()` was executed on the element pointed by `this` (`this.prop("disabled", false)`, but being into a callback it was binding to the wrong element, so I had to do the common `var that = this` workaround. Trying to play with `.apply()`/`.call()` was not working well; I don't know why. Double check with a `console.log(this)` if it is set to your desired object, just before calling `this.prop(...)`

Comment: I nominate this answer as a candidate for conversion over to the document section. Clear, complete, well-written.

Comment: .prop("disabled", false) does not work, the result is disable="", and the field stays disabled. The solution for me was $('#field').removeAttr('disabled');

Comment: _By using removeAttr(), you are completely removing the disabled attribute itself - while prop() is merely setting the property's underlying boolean value to false._

I don't believe this to be true. In HTML, the mere presence of the `disabled` property will disable the element. For example, having a `<button disabled="false"></button>`  will not enable the button, the property must be removed.

By calling `$('button').prop('disabled', false);` jQuery will remove the property for you, as I observed in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aMJELv) (inspect to see the property removal).

Answer (score 79):

to remove disabled attribute use,

```
 $("#elementID").removeAttr('disabled');
```

and to add disabled attribute use,

```
$("#elementID").prop("disabled", true);
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 45):

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="inputDisabled" value="">
​<button id="edit">Edit</button>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

$("#edit").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.inputDisabled').removeAttr("disabled")
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZwHfY/

Answer (score 18):

Use like this,

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="inputDisabled" value="">

<div id="edit">edit</div>
```

**JS:**

```
 $('#edit').click(function(){ // click to
            $('.inputDisabled').attr('disabled',false); // removing disabled in this class
 });
```

Comment: This one is actually working for me. The prop('disabled', false) surprisingly didn't work.

Comment: @Stefan same thing here! Did you find out why?

Comment: I know this is an ancient thread but if someone still struggles with this, my issue was that the element was an `<a>`, on which `.prop('disabled', false)` doesn't work. I changed it to a `<button>` and it works now

Answer (score 9):

I think you are trying to **toggle** the disabled state, in witch case you should use this (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903293/toggle-disabled-attribute-in-jquery)):

```
$(".inputDisabled").prop('disabled', function (_, val) { return ! val; });
```

[Here is a working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZwHfY/1/)

Answer (score 8):

#### for removing the disabled properties

```
 $('#inputDisabled').removeAttr('Disabled');
```

#### for adding the disabled properties

```
 $('#inputDisabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled' );
```

Comment: That answer has been given previously, but it's still wrong. You're calling attributes "properties", which is confusing.

Answer (score 5):

### 2018, without JQuery

*I know the question is about JQuery: this answer is just FYI.*

```
document.getElementById('edit').addEventListener(event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.inputDisabled')].map(e => e.disabled = false);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Thought this you can easily setup

```
$(function(){
$("input[name^=radio_share]").click
(
    function()
    {
        if($(this).attr("id")=="radio_share_dependent")
        {
            $(".share_dependent_block input, .share_dependent_block select").prop("disabled",false);   
        }
        else
        {
            $(".share_dependent_block input, .share_dependent_block select").prop("disabled",true);   
        }
    }
 );
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This was the only code that worked for me:

```
element.removeProp('disabled')
```

Note that it's `removeProp` and not `removeAttr`.

I'm using `jQuery 2.1.3` here.

Comment: From jQuery documentation:

Important: the .removeProp() method should not be used to set these properties to false. Once a native property is removed, it cannot be added again. See .removeProp() for more information.

Answer (score 2):

This question specifically mentions jQuery, but if you are looking to accomplish this without jQuery, the equivalent in vanilla JavaScript is:

```
elem.removeAttribute('disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try special selector:

Not working : `$('#ID_Unit').removeAttr("disabled");`
Works : `$('select[id=ID_Unit]:disabled').removeAttr("disabled");`

all "select" controls `$('select:disabled').removeAttr("disabled");`

"select" is control type like "type" etc.