# how to disable submit button until form is filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know there is a lot answers for that out-there, but from some reason it not working for me.

You can view the code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqwcu/)

There is mistake on the position of the script? with one of the inputs id ?

The problem: after fill the text fields, the button still disabled.

## HTML

```
<form class="form" name="contactform" method="post" action="https://lp.outit.co.il/LA-FACE/send_form_email.php">
    <input  placeholder="Your Name*"  type="text" name="name" maxlength="50">
    <input placeholder="Phone *"   type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30">                    
    <input placeholder="Email *"   type="email" name="email" maxlength="80">
    <input class="send" id="register" type="submit" value="Send" disabled="disabled">

    <p>* = Requierd fields</p>

</form>
```

## JQUERY ON HEAD

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
(function() {
$('form > input').keyup(function() {

  var empty = false;
  $('form > input').each(function() {
  if ($(this).val() === '') {
  empty = true;
  }
  });

  if (empty) {
    $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
    $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
  });
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Your fiddle is working properly as expected .Whats the problem?Form is not submitting till i fill data.Its ok.Whats wrong?

Comment: How its working? for me after fill the text fields, the button still disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted working fiddle ,Is this what u want ?   http://jsfiddle.net/qqwcu/2/

Note its preferred to use:  `$('#register').prop("disabled", false);`
Check this [Remove disabled attribute using JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626517/remove-disabled-attribute-using-jquery)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('form > input').keyup(function() {

var empty1 = false;
$('form > input').each(function() {
if ($(this).val() === '') {
 empty1 = true;
}
});

if (empty1) {
$('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
} else {

     $('#register').prop("disabled", false);
}
});
});
```

Comment: why all the minus on my question. its fact - something not work for me, jsfiddle is just for the example, on the site it not working, i think its legitimacy question

Comment: Your site is working well.Whats the problem,I filled all fields and it submitted.You please Press LONG: CTRL+F5 to clear cache and test again.

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle is fine, although ,You havent included jQuery there. Did  that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is run, when the DOM is not yet ready.

Sor wrap it with

```
$(document).ready()
```