# Disable form button unless all text input fields are filled in

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form that has multiple text inputs, I don't want to add id to each one as they are generated from server side code - number of fields may differ etc. I just want to be able to disable the submit button until there is text entered into each text input.

I have gotten this far, but only disables button until text entered in to one text input field - I want it to stay disabled until text entered in to **all** text inputs.

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#button').attr('disabled', true);

            $('input:text').keyup(function () {
                $('#button').prop('disabled', this.value == "" ? true : false);
            })
        });
    </script>
```

I have also tried `$('input:text').each().keyup(function (){` - but does not make button clickable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978175/how-to-disable-submit-button-until-form-is-filled

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery disable/enable submit button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594952/jquery-disable-enable-submit-button)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('#button').attr('disabled', true);
$('input:text').keyup(function () {
   var disable = false;
       $('input:text').each(function(){
            if($(this).val()==""){
                 disable = true;      
            }
       });
  $('#button').prop('disabled', disable);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yy4jr8qn/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

The callback function for keyup now checks only that specific input field's value (`this.value`). Instead, this needs to loop through all input fields that need to be filled, and only when all have text do you change the the `.prop` value.

```
$('input:text').keyup(function () {
    $('#button').prop('disabled', allFieldsAreFilled());
});

function allFieldsAreFilled() {
    var allFilled = true;
    // check all input text fields
    $("#yourForm input:text"]).each(function () {
        // if one of them is emptyish allFilled is no longer true
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            allFilled = false;
        }
    });
    return allFilled;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  var bool = true, flag = false;
  $('#button').prop('disabled', bool); // use prop to disable the button

  $(document).keyup(function() { // listen the keyup on the document or you can change to form in case if you have or you can try the closest div which contains the text inputs
    $('input:text').each(function() { // loop through each text inputs
      bool = $.trim(this.value) === "" ?  true :  false; // update the var bool with boolean values
      if(bool)
      return flag;
    });
    $('#button').prop('disabled', bool); // and apply the boolean here to enable
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' />
<input type='text' />
<input type='text' />
<input type='text' />
<input type='text' />
<input type='button' id='button' value='button' />
```

Comment: Enter text in last textbox and check what happen? It enabled the the button.