# My Jquery button- disable/enable function is not working. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to disable submit button until first two fields have input. I've written a function to do that but for some reason it's not working.
Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<Head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="Stuff.js"></script>
</Head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group has-error">
                <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="First" placeholder="First Name">
            </div>
    <div class="form-group">
                <label for="LastName">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Last" placeholder="Last Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Age">Age</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Age" placeholder="Age">
     </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit"  >Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is my function:

```
$('#submit').keyup(function () {
if ($('#First').val() != "" && $('#Last').val() != "") {
    $('#submit').removeattr('disabled');
} else {
    $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
}
```

});

Comment: why you are using functions on keyup? why not on onClick?

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this:

```
$('#First, #Last').keyup(function () {
  if ($('#First').val() !== "" && $('#Last').val() !== "") {
    $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

Note that you need to check the fields themselves upon keyup.

Also, use `prop()` to set the underlying boolean property of the disabled attribute to true/false, instead of removing it completely - [see here for why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626517/remove-disabled-attribute-using-jquery/13626565#13626565).

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/n88dqqao/)