# How to remove disable element using JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use `jQuery 1.8.3`.

Here is my html input text box:

```
<input type="text" name="textinput-hide" id="textinput1" placeholder="Text input" value="" disabled>
```

Here how I try to remove disable element:

```
  $('#textinput1').removeProp('disabled');
```

But the row above dosn't remove `disabled`  attribute. How to remove disable element

Comment: you want to remove attribute or complete element that have disable attribute?

Comment: `$('#textinput1').removeAttr('disabled');`

Comment: $('#textinput1').remove();

Comment: this link may be help you..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626517/remove-disabled-attribute-using-jquery

Comment: Here is what jQuery says about `removeProp`:

Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use `.prop()` to set these properties to false instead.

Comment: `$('#textinput1').prop("disabled", false)` is pretty helpful

Comment: Simply  use `$( "input:disabled" ).remove();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***If you want to remove `disable` attribute:-***

```js
$('input').each(function(){
  if($(this).prop("disabled")){
    $(this).prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="textinput-hide" id="textinput1" placeholder="Text input1" value="" disabled><br><br>

<input type="text" name="textinput-hide" id="textinput2" placeholder="Text input2" value="">
```

***If you want to remove complete element itself:-***

```js
$('input').each(function(){
  if($(this).prop("disabled")){
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="textinput-hide" id="textinput1" placeholder="Text input1" value="" disabled><br>

<input type="text" name="textinput-hide" id="textinput2" placeholder="Text input2" value="">
```

Comment: I try this     $('#textinput1').prop("disabled", false); but it dosent work

Comment: @Michael  working in my code.So i din't get you why it not worked for you.Create a fiddle example of your problem and i will rectify that