# Removing disabled attribute in chosen not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove the chosen disabled attribute but not working.

```
$('#check_book').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: Can you describe what you think this line of code does?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove disabled attribute using JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626517/remove-disabled-attribute-using-jquery)

Comment: Actually i'm trying to remove the disabled property in select tag from java script.
<select name="check_book" id="check_book" onchange="(this.value)" disabled="disabled" class="font_size demo-chosen-select "  data-placeholder="<?php echo translate('select_check_book'); ?>" tabindex="2" >
                       <option></option>
                     
                   </select>

Comment: removeAttr() perhaps?

Comment: removeAttr() not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it

```
$('#check_book').removeAttr('disabled', true).trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Answer (score 0):

to add disabled attribute use,

```
$('#check_book').prop('disabled', true);
```

to remove disabled attribute use

```
$('#check_book').prop('disabled', false);
```

or use

```
$('#check_book').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: I tried this but not working $('#check_book').removeAttr('disabled');

Comment: when i removed class atrribute its working otherwise not

Comment: can you try the $('#check_book').prop('disabled', false); @SohailAhmad

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has 
[.removeProp()](https://api.jquery.com/removeProp/) method, try this

```
$('#check_book').removeProp('disabled');
```