# JQuery remove disabled attribute doesn't work

Tags: jquery, properties, attributes

It's very weird but I can't remove the disabled property from input, the selector is right, I can hide it for exemple :

```
jQuery(".hideit1").hide();`
```

**My input:**

```
<input title="Adresse" name="billing[street][]" id="billing:street1" value="" id0="route" style="display: inline-block;" class="hideit1 input-text  required-entry disabled" type="text">
```

**I tried:**

```
jQuery(".hideit1").prop("disabled", false);
jQuery(".hideit1").removeAttr("disabled");
jQuery(".hideit1").prop('disabled', function (_, val) { return ! val; });
jQuery(".hideit1").removeProp('disabled');
```

All the solutions of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626517/remove-disabled-attribute-using-jquery) post.

Comment: That element is not disabled...? It only has a `disabled` class, which is not the same thing

Comment: I don't know why I did not see that it was a `class` and not `prop`, it's definitely tired, thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `disabled` attribute in your element, instead it have a class `disabled` so you could use the jQuery method `.removeClass()` to remove it like :

```
jQuery(".hideit1").removeClass("disabled");
```

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $(".hideit1").removeClass("disabled");
}, 1000);
```

```css
.disabled {
  background-color: #dadbdc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input title="Adresse" name="billing[street][]" id="billing:street1" value="" id0="route" style="display: inline-block;" class="hideit1 input-text  required-entry disabled" type="text">
```

Comment: Fu** Yes really it is a class and not a property, thanks

Comment: :D that happen brother, don't worry

Comment: That's it, Yaatik essaha

Answer (score 1):

You have used a class, not an attribute. Use `removeClass` method instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
jQuery(".hideit1").removeClass('disabled');
```

or

```
jQuery(".hideit1").toggleClass('disabled');
```

You are trying to remove a property that isn't set, when it should be the class.