# jQuery remove attribute before appending HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append HTML of an element, the `HTML` consists of different inputs, each of the inputs has an attribute `disabled`. How can I remove that attribute before appending?

The following code appends without removing the disabled attribute. If I try something like `find('select').removeAttr('disabled');` then it removes all other html and dispalys only that part.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){

var content = $(this).parent().find('.temp').html();

//content1 = $(content).find('select').removeAttr('disabled');

$('.list').append(content);

});
```

```css
.temp {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
 
  <button>Add</button>

  <div class="list">
    <p>content</p>    
  </div>

<div class="temp">
  
  <div class="row">
    <select disabled>
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" disabled>
  </div>      
      
 </div>
```

Comment: Check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery

Also this one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626517/how-to-remove-disabled-attribute-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){

var content = $(this).parent().find('.temp');

content.find('select').removeAttr('disabled');

$('.list').append(content.html());

});
```

```css
.temp {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
 
  <button>Add</button>

  <div class="list">
    <p>content</p>    
  </div>

<div class="temp">
  
  <div class="row">
    <select disabled>
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" disabled>
  </div>      
      
 </div>
```

Comment: Referring Jquery removeAttr doc - https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

Note: Removing an inline onclick event handler using .removeAttr() doesn't achieve the desired effect in Internet Explorer 8, 9 and 11. To avoid potential problems, use .prop() instead.


Check if this `NOTE` is applicable on `DISABLED` props

Answer (score 0):

You can create HTML snippets to JS file, add append it

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  const html = `
    <select>
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text">
  `;
  $('.list').append(html);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">

  <button>Add</button>

  <div class="list">
    <p>content</p>
  </div>

</div>
```